# Change selectbox to textfield and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table in which there are three columns `(A: datefield, B: selectbox, C: checkbox)`.

Now when someone checks on the checkbox, the `column(B)` having selectbox should convert to a column textfield. That means I want to convert selectbox to textfield and vice versa on change of the checkbox event. Is that possible?? If so how? (using js, no jquery please)

Reply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: u tried anything yet ???

Comment: You'll have to do it by hand in JS using a `change` listener on the `<select>`.

Comment: If i understand it correctly did you tried using `DataList`instead of `Select` You can try to [have look of it here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)

Comment: @CoolGurl, can you share your html and javascript, if any?

Comment: I got it... ".checked" event worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below,

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function toggleSelect() {
    var isChecked = document.getElementById("check").checked;
        if(isChecked) {
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='txt'></input>";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "<select> <option value='1'>1</option> </select> ";
    }
    //alert(isChecked);
}
</script>
    <table> 
        <tr> 
            <td> DateField </td>
            <td id="toggle"> 
                <select> <option value="1">1</option> </select> 
            </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" id="check" onchange="javascript:toggleSelect();">change</input></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place two div tags where

one contains the component which you want to change (for this div give a class name "comp1 visible" and in the CSS   set the style has `display: block` )

and another one div with the component you would want to replace ( for this div give a class name "comp2 hidden" and in the CSS set the style has `display:none` )

use the onclick event to call the function ...

```
function insertitem(rvalue){
            if(rvalue.value==1){
                var temp=document.getElementsByClassName("comp1");


            temp[0].classList.remove("hidden");
            temp[0].classList.add("visible");
            }
            else if(rvalue.value==2){
                var temp=document.getElementsByClassName("comp2");

            temp[0].classList.remove("hidden");
            temp[0].classList.add("visible");

            }
        }
```

this should work.. PS: since you dint post any of ur code .. i couldnt explain much